# How to do infinite string based on index and length in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to do a method that takes three parameters. A string, index, and length.
I'm trying to create an infinite string.

**Example:**
`method("book",-3,9)`

**Output:**
`ookbookbo`

**Example 2:** `method("book",-5,15)`

**Output 2** `kbookbookbookbo`

My code so far:

```
def create_sequence(string, index, length):
    positive_index = abs(index)
    l = list(string)
    end = ""
    print(length- positive_index - len(l))
    for i in range(length- positive_index - len(l)):

        end += l[i]
    output = ''.join([string,end])
```

My logic : The string will always be used, so I just have to get the right-end part of the sequence and the beginning(left sided) part, and then just attach them together. The end part in my code works as long as `length - positive_index - len(l)` is less than or equal to the string length.. I also don't know how to get the sequence part that come before the original string.

I'm a beginner in python, any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I want my input string to be the base. As in book, has 0,1,2 and 3 indices for each letter in it. All the added characters to the left of "0" which is "b" in book have negative indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about wihout any loop?

We have 3 part:
`Begin of string`, `Middle (repetition of word "book")` and `End`

```
def create_sequence(string, index, length):
    word_length=len(string)
    string_repetition=((length+index)//word_length+(-index)//word_length) #How many full strings we have
    string_end=(length+index)%word_length #How manny letters are left after last full word
    inf_string_start= string[length-string_repetition*word_length:]
    inf_string_mid=string_repetition*string#MID
    inf_string_end=string[:string_end] #END
    inf_string=inf_string_start+inf_string_mid+inf_string_end #concatenation

    return inf_string
```

However `itertools` may be more friendly to use. But you can consider this solution if you don't want to use external libs.

Comment: No _explicit_ loops, but of course there are still many _hidden_ loops in there, e.g. with `*`, meaning the complexity is not O(1) (you did not say that, but it might be inferred from the wording).

Comment: Yes but I think you still will have benefits on performance if the `inf_string` would be very long.

Comment: Also, this contains syntax errors (and is missing `return`) and after fixing those errors (guessing what you meant to do) it does not produce the right output...

Comment: Yeah I did it fast in simple notepad. I edited my answer with correct syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Just use modulo `%` to "normalize" the index to the length of the string:

```
def create_sequence(string, start, length):
    return ''.join(string[i % len(string)] for i in range(start, start + length))

>>> create_sequence("book", -3, 9)
'ookbookbo'
>>> create_sequence("book", -5, 15)
'kbookbookbookbo'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools` to create something similar

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = itertools.islice(itertools.cycle("book"), 1,5)
>>> ''.join(x)
'ookb'
>>> x = itertools.islice(itertools.cycle("book"), 3,9)
>>> ''.join(x)
'kbookb'
>>> x = itertools.islice(itertools.cycle("book"), 3,10)
>>> ''.join(x)
'kbookbo'
```

Updated as per @tobias_k suggestion for handling negative indexes,

```
>>> def mkseq(string, index, length):
...   return ''.join(itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(string), index % len(string), index % len(string) + length))
... 
>>> mkseq("book", -3, 9)
'ookbookbo'
```

Comment: Thank you. But my method design is a bit different, I'm trying not to use built in functions. I want my input string to be the base. As in book, has 0,1,2 and 3 indices for each letter in it. All the added characters to the left of "0" which is "b" in book have negative indices.

Comment: Why not use built-in? This will be both clearer and faster

Comment: For negative indices, you can still use `''.join(islice(cycle(string), index % len(string), index % len(string) + length))`